# fatal: unable to access “…”: gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed

Tags: git, github, syslinux, gitlab

I've been using Git for the past few months. Recently when I try to clone or to push, I keep on getting this error. I've researched on the internet but so far no solution has worked for me. Does anyone have an idea?

External note : Now I moved to different country, it was working perfectly where I was before. Git Version : 2.11.0 , OS : Debian GNU/Linux 9.11 (stretch)

Error :
git push or git clone
fatal: unable to access 'https://**************/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed

Answer (score 1):

I get "`gnutls_handshake() failed`" message as well.
You could try to compile git with OpenSSL instead of gnutls using [Paul N. Baker's shell script](https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/git-openssl-shellscript/blob/master/compile-git-with-openssl.sh).

This shell script works for me.